# Rails 3: Sharing letters with users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on an app and I have a model called letter where a user can write a letter for their own purpose or write it and share it with a specific user that is following them. I have the following users implemented already but I am unsure on how to share letters with a user that is following you. Many people suggest sharing actual files but I would like to share the letters that you would write and published in rails. What way should I go about implementing this in rails 3 or is there anything to at least get me going in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

If i'm following you correctly when a user creates a letter they can choose to show or not show just that specific letter with their followers.

If so you'll need a followers model.
Then users has_many followers.

Then the letter should have a column that is something like 'visible_to_followers'.

Then in the UI when creating the letter the user can choose if that particular letter
is visible to their followers.

Note if you wanted to limit the letter to specific followers and not all of the users followers that would change the design a bit.

Hope this helps a little!

Comment: You have a good understanding so far. How would I go about only showing it to a specific follower. I know I can pull the following list using a collection tag but far as sharing the note I am not sure where to begin.

Comment: If you wanted to choose a subset of followers to share the letter with on your UI you would need a multi select box that would be filled with users.followers.  Then the user could choose who he wants.  You'd need a table that was letter_followers or something then though.  It would contain the letter_id and the id's of the users who may follow it ( Those selected from the UI )